# Signature: FAILED - CSR has an invalid signature

Tags: private-key, public-key, csr

I have generated csr in my MAC machine using this project https://github.com/cbaker6/CertificateSigningRequest. The private key and public key were stored in login keychain of device's keychain. All steps are passed, however after generating csr, the csr signature seems invalid. The keySize also not shown in CSR decoder. How can i resolve the issue?

Comment: please show your parsed data with openssl csr command or openssl asn1parse command so other can help your exact issue.